# Анимация border

Tags: jquery, css3, css-animation

Здравствуйте!

Есть вот такое меню:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="">пункт 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">пункт 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">пункт 3</a></li>
<li><a href="">пункт 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Для активного пункта меню добавляется класс active:

```
.active {
    border: 2px solid #927253;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на любой из пунктов рамка (класс active) плавно перемещалась от предыдущего пункта к текущему? Что-то вроде slide эффекта для рамки от одного пункта меню к другому.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/6d2sj5Lb/1/

Попробуйте так:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
       .active {
            border: 2px solid #927253;
            border-radius: 20px;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
            height: 15px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="active"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="first">пункт 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">пункт 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">пункт 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">пункт 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var offset = $('.first').offset();
            $('.active').offset({top: offset.top + 1, left: offset.left});
    
            $('a').mouseover(function () {
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                $('.active').animate({
                    top: offset.top - 7,
                    left: offset.left - 8
                }, 900);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Скорость перемещения можно менять во втором параметре функции animate()